# jquery issue in getting value by name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

`<%= attendance_form_id %>` in jquery contains dynamic unique id of table generated in html view. 
i am trying to get radio button value by name attribute `project_director[status]`.that has same attribute name inside every unique id. i am using alert to get value.

currently my code correctly alerts form submitted value on first page load submission. but second submission onward it alerts first submission alert value. once i reload page it works correct first time.

how can i make alert work correct all time.

js

```
<script>
   $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
     $('#<%= attendance_form_id %>').on('ajax:success', function(event){
      const [data, status, xhr] = event.detail
      //alert(status)
      value = $('input[name="project_director[status]"]:checked').val();
      alert(value)
      $('#<%= attendance_form_id %>').hide()
     }).on('ajax:error',function(event){
        alert("Something went wrong, please reload page")
     });
   });
</script>
```

html code

```
<table id="attendance_form_29">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <ul>
               <div>
                  <div class="wrapper-class">
                     <input type="radio" value="true" name="project_director[status]" id="project_director_status_true">
                     <label for="project_director_approve">Approve</label>
                     <br>
                     <input type="radio" value="false" name="project_director[status]" id="project_director_status_false">
                     <label for="project_director_reject">Reject</label>
                  </div>
  
               </div>
            </ul>
         </td>
         <td>
            <input value="4" type="hidden" name="project_director[user_id]" id="project_director_user_id">
            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" class="button primary small" data-disable-with="Submit">
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to get value of `input[name="project_director[status]"]` inside the form that has `<%= attendance_form_id %>` id. In this case `$('input[name="project_director[status]"]:checked').val()` will not work as expected because you have multiple input with this name as mentioned (*has same attribute name inside every unique id*). To make it work, you can use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
 $('#<%= attendance_form_id %>').on('ajax:success', function(event){
  const [data, status, xhr] = event.detail;
  //change here
  value = $('#<%= attendance_form_id %>').find('input[name="project_director[status]"]:checked').val(); 
  alert(value)
  $('#<%= attendance_form_id %>').hide()
 }).on('ajax:error',function(event){
    alert("Something went wrong, please reload page")
 });
});
```

Comment: maybe you have no checked radio

Comment: i checked radio button issue is same for all forms

Comment: Can you try `console.log($(this).find('input[name="project_director[status]"]').val())`?

Comment: ```console.log($(this).find('input[name="project_director[status]"]').val())``` same output as ```undefined```

Comment: how about `console.log($('#<%= attendance_form_id %>').find('input[name="project_director[status]"]:checked').val())`?

Comment: ```console.log($('#attendance_form_29').find('input[name="project_director[status]"]').val())``` return ```true ```  #<%= attendance_form_id %> is compiled by server and in browser it's ```#attendance_form_29```